# Deepin Desktop Context Menu

Tags: desktop-environment, menu, deepin

I am having difficulty figuring out where and how to edit my desktop context menu. I am using Deepin desktop environment and file manager on Arch Linux, and am simply trying to edit the "New File" options.

As it is, I have options to create various Office documents and plain text files. I would like to add my own templates, and remove the Office documents, as I do not need/use them. I found the `/usr/share/dde-file-manager/templates` directory, which contains the templates, but simply creating/deleting those does nothing, and they are regenerated if deleted.

I have searched what seems like everywhere, and am unable to locate where to edit these, and online seems to have millions of examples of making edits to Ubuntu and Nautilus, which does not seem to apply.

Does anyone happen to know where the .conf (or whatever it is...) file to edit these entries is located?